# WebView Save login session for future login

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm Using `WebView` in my Mac os x application to load Instagram account:

```
NSString * urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.instagram.com/"];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
[[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

After the page is load i can do manual login to Instagram account but after couple of hours the login session is removed and i need to login again to the account.

I must say this case is only in Regular applicaion run and when the app is in Debug mode and run from XCode the login to the Instagram account is always login.

Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: You can't use `UIWebView` in macOS. It's only available for iOS. Did you mean `WKWebView`?

Comment: @rmaddy i'm using WebView and not WKWebView

Comment: WebView isn't available in iOS, only macOS. Please note that the documentation for `WebView` clearly states you should be using `WKWebView`.